Supporting both char** and const char** function call
I am using a library that in early versions has a function declaration
int foo(char **);

which later evolved (without changing the internals) into
int foo(const char **);

and I want to have my program compileable with both.
However, when I do a
int bar() {
  char **c;

[…] // creation of c

  return foo(c);
}

I get a compilation error with newer C compilers (gcc-14):
In function ‘bar’:
error: passing argument 1 of ‘foo’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    5 |   return foo(c);
      |       ^
      |       |
      |       char **
note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
    1 | int foo(const char **);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

Using the const modifier for c would prevent compilation with the old version of the library, and would also need type casts that remove the const modifier during the initialization of c.
What would be the way to support both old and new versions of the library, and why does the error appear at all? I do not want to just switch off the error generation, but instead be C conform.

Don't change the interface  for for  old clients.  For example by version it (probably too late now).  Manipulate the header search path so the right header is picked up.  Update the clients to use the new interface with casts.  See if  gcc  -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types disables the check.

It is not my library, so this is not my decision. And the compiler flag would remove the error, but I don't want to use it because it is very helpful on other places. And it is compiler dependent, which is bad for distributing portable C code.

Wrap the upstream library and expose two functions.   Use a define  to call the right function in the client.

It is not my interface but the one from a library. In fact foo() comes from libXaw which has different declarations on Debian and Arch Linux.

It doesn't matter whose fault it is just the constraints and giving your ideas on how to handle the current situation.  If you want your clients to be compatible then then you need a cast somewhere.  Conditional compilation, or state your code version x works with library y and x+1 works with library y+1.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378560/how-to-disable-gcc-warnings-for-a-few-lines-of-code gets around the all or nothing.  I still think my answer is the way to go, though.

The reason for the compilation error is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016098/implicit-conversion-from-char-to-const-char

this gives a more detailed explanation of the reason why it is not working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783534/expected-expected-const-char-but-argument-is-of-type-char

Why it isn't working:
Passing something to a function in C is done "as if by assignment" - the rules of assignment apply. And among these rules is one that allows us to assign an object of type* to a const type* pointer. We may add const implicitly, but not the other way around. This is an universal rule and pointers to pointers are no different - a pointer to pointer is still a "pointer to type" like anything else.
If the pointer to pointer happens to point at a const-qualified object then that pointed-at item, a const char*, is a different type than a char*, because pointers are only compatible if they have exactly the same qualifiers.
In your case you have a char** which is a pointer to char*. And you try to assign it to a const char** which is a pointer to const char*. So you don't have the previously mentioned situation of assigning a type* to a const type*. Rather, you have type* (pointer to char*) and try to assign it to some_other_type* (pointer to const char*).

How to fix it:
Doing a quick and dirty cast to (const char**) would work, but it's neither pretty nor type safe. What you could do instead is to create a macro acting as function wrapper:
int foo (const char **);
#define foo(c) foo( _Generic((c),                    \
                      char**:       (const char**)c, \
                      const char**: c) )

int bar() {
  char **c;

  return foo(c);
}


The function is always using const char** now.
If the passed argument is of type char** and only then, it is cast to const char**.
If the passed argument is const char** as expected, all good, pass it along.
Otherwise if the passed argument is something else, there will be a compiler error.


This is the closest thing that works, that I could throw together.
Few notes:

it breaks a lot of variable safety standards, by forcefully bringing both variables and function to matching argument types
the current implementation of the macro declares a function pointer before calling it - in my short time i could not manage to do it without declaring a variable
the macro usage is ugly

It at least compiles in gcc
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int foo0(char **var)
{
    printf("foo0 var: %s\n", *var);
    return 0;
}

int foo1(const char **var)
{
    printf("foo1 var: %s\n", *var);
    return 1;
}

typedef int (*f_foo)(const char **var);
#define CALL_FOO(_foo, _var)\
    f_foo _foo##_ptr = (f_foo)_foo;\
    _foo##_ptr((const char **)_var);

int main()
{
    char **c;

    c = malloc(100);

    strcpy(*c, "dynamic string");

    //foo0(c);
    //foo1(c);

    CALL_FOO(foo0, c);
    CALL_FOO(foo1, c);

    free(c);

    return 0;
}

EDIT: you could declare the function pointers globally, then just call them trough the macro, or have a dedicated inline function

An option for dealing with this cleanly in C semantics is simply to use either a char ** or const char ** according to the type of foo:
int bar(void)
{
    union { char **c; const char **cc; } u;

    #define c _Generic(foo, int (*)(char **): u.c, default: u.cc)

    … // Assignment to c.

    return foo(c);

    #undef c
}

The reason automatic conversion of char ** to const char ** is not allowed is given here.
